# Convert old md5 passwords to password_hash

Tags: php, md5

Having trouble updating old md5 passwords to password_hash on a php site 
ive been able to update all files to password_hash im just stuck on updating old passwords in the database when a member next logs in

here original code

```
    $password = passhash($_POST["password"]);

    if (!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $res = SQL_Query_exec("SELECT id, password, secret, status, enabled FROM users WHERE username = " . sqlesc($_POST["username"]) . "");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

        if ( ! $row || $row["password"] != $password )
            $message = T_("LOGIN_INCORRECT");
        elseif ($row["status"] == "pending")
            $message = T_("ACCOUNT_PENDING");
        elseif ($row["enabled"] == "no")
            $message = T_("ACCOUNT_DISABLED");
    } else
        $message = T_("NO_EMPTY_FIELDS");
```

heres with password_hash

```
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    if (!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $res = SQL_Query_exec("SELECT id, password, secret, status, enabled FROM users WHERE username = " . sqlesc($_POST["username"]) . "");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

        if ( !$row || !password_verify($password,$row["password"]))
            $message = T_("LOGIN_INCORRECT");
        elseif ($row["status"] == "pending")
            $message = T_("ACCOUNT_PENDING");
        elseif ($row["enabled"] == "no")
            $message = T_("ACCOUNT_DISABLED");
    } else
        $message = T_("NO_EMPTY_FIELDS");
```

i think it should be something like this but cant seem to get it working just before the verify line

```
   if (strlen($password) > 40)
   {
   // Password already converted, verify using password_verify
   } else {

// User still using the old MD5, update it!
    if ($password = passhash($_POST["password"]))
    {
    // update to password_hash
    SQL_Query_exec("UPDATE users SET password WHERE username = " . 
    sqlesc($_POST["username"]) . "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your query `UPDATE users SET password WHERE username = ....` doesn't actually update anything.

Answer (score 4):

I would advice you to keep the old `password` in the database, for the time being, and create a new, more properly named, `passwordHash` next to it. This way you can always fall back to the old way of doing things, in case you make a mistake.

When an user logs in you have indeed access to the unhashed password. At that point you can create the [new hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php):

```
$password = $_POST["password"];
$passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

After that you need to actually store the new hash:

```
SQL_Query_exec("UPDATE users 
                SET passwordHash = " . sqlesc($passwordHash) . "
                WHERE username = " . sqlesc($_POST["username"]));
```

Using the new hash is then simply a question of checking whether the new hash is present, or not. If it is not, you create it, otherwise you use it.

After a while, when you know the new hash is working reliably, you can remove the old MD5 hashes from your database for users that have a new hash (after making a backup!).

**Note:** You're escaping user input, instead of using prepared statements. That is not the best option. See: [How to Prevent SQL Injection Vulnerabilities in PHP Applications](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/prevent-sql-injection-vulnerabilities-in-php-applications/) where it says:

> Do not sanitize user input by escaping or removing special characters.
>   An attacker can use encoding to bypass such protection.

Or look in [the PHP manual itself](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) where it says:

> Use prepared statements with bound variables.

Answer (score -1):

In that last example it looks like you're checking the length of the inputted password and not the hashed password. You need to get the password from the db first

```
if (!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"]))
{
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $res = SQL_Query_exec("SELECT id, password, secret, status, enabled FROM users WHERE username = " . sqlesc($_POST["username"]) . "");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    if(strlen($row["password"]) == 40) // New hash
    {
        if ( !$row || !password_verify($password,$row["password"]))
            $message = T_("LOGIN_INCORRECT");
        elseif ($row["status"] == "pending")
            $message = T_("ACCOUNT_PENDING");
        elseif ($row["enabled"] == "no")
            $message = T_("ACCOUNT_DISABLED");
    }
    else                                // Old hash
    {
        $doUpdate = 1;
        $oldhash = passhash($password);
        if ( ! $row || $row["password"] != $oldhash )
        {
            $doUpdate = 0;
            $message = T_("LOGIN_INCORRECT");
        }
        elseif ($row["status"] == "pending")
            $message = T_("ACCOUNT_PENDING");
        elseif ($row["enabled"] == "no")
            $message = T_("ACCOUNT_DISABLED");
        if($doUpdate == 1) // Assuming all went well
                SQL_Query_exec("UPDATE users SET password = '" . newpasshashfunction($password) . "' WHERE username = " . sqlesc($_POST["username"]) . "");
    }
}
else
    $message = T_("NO_EMPTY_FIELDS");
```

This code can be cleaned up quite a bit